# git rebase - pop each commit into working dir to easily edit, re-use commit msg

Tags: git-rebase

The `git-rebase` `edit` command seems to have the right idea, but we have to run `git undo; git reset;` to make changes available to edit....

Is there a good way to be able to cruise through an entire set of commits, pop each one into the working dir, one after the next?

Before I submit my PRs, I like to go through my commits. Instead of just looking at a read-only diff, I want to live edit each commit, as if I had just written it.

I also want the commit message to be pre-populated, don't want to go hunting for the correct commit message each time.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the `edit` cmd inside `git-rebase` doesn't quite do all the steps you need to do to actually edit (mutate) a commit.

First, you may decide, you don't want to look at merge conflicts.

```bash
git rebase --strategy recursive --strategy-option theirs -i <base-sha>
```

Since you are going to check/edit each commit... if you aren't changing too many things, you should be able to spot what is wrong about a commit, based on a previous change you did. Notably, if you added a code comment in an early commit, and saw a subsequent commit deletes that comment, you should simply restore the comment. This is easy in vscode's side by side diff view (which I use all the time).

Finally, we do need to use some sort of rebase `exec` command to pop changes into our working directory:

```
exec MSG=$(git log -1 --format=%B HEAD); git undo; git reset; echo "$MSG" > $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG; echo "editing commit:\n\n$MSG\n";
```

Maybe, you use vscode, we can also open the edited files for you:

```bash
code $(git diff --staged --name-only)
```

UPDATE: This doesn't open the actual diffs, so is a waste for me, not included in final command. Maybe a vscode shortcut key would work, or if this entire review flow was simply packaged up into a vscode extension.

This exec command will always fail, so we'll want `--no-reschedule-failed-exec`

// Putting it all together ... there are further changes below.

```bash
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=: git rebase --exec 'MSG=$(git log -1 --format=%B HEAD); git undo; git restore --staged $(git diff --name-only --staged --diff-filter=r); echo "$MSG" > $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG; echo "editing commit:\n\n$MSG\n";' --strategy recursive --no-reschedule-failed-exec --strategy-option theirs -i 315abbd5b
```

To cycle onto the next commit, simply run:

```
git add --all && git commit && git rebase --continue
```

We'll then need this `prepare-commit-msg` script to re-use the `LAST_COMMIT_MSG` file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
# COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
# SHA1=$3

if [ -f $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG ]; then
  cat $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG $COMMIT_MSG_FILE > temp_commit_msg && mv temp_commit_msg $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
  rm $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG
fi
```

Add this few hooks to wipe any stale `LAST_COMMIT_MSG`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

echo "some git-hook: wiping $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG: $(cat $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG)"
rm $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG
```

This way, you just run `git commit` when you are done editing a commit, and, you'll get to re-use/tweak the original commit message.

If using `husky`, you'll need to:

```bash
echo ".husky/prepare-commit-msg" >> $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/../main-worktree/.git/info/exclude
echo ".husky/pre-rebase" >> $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/../main-worktree/.git/info/exclude
echo ".husky/post-rewrite" >> $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/../main-worktree/.git/info/exclude
echo ".husky/post-commit" >> $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/../main-worktree/.git/info/exclude
 # paste it in:
code -n .husky/prepare-commit-msg .husky/pre-rebase .husky/post-rewrite .husky/post-commit
chmod +x .husky/prepare-commit-msg
chmod +x .husky/pre-rebase
chmod +x .husky/post-rewrite
chmod +x .husky/post-commit
```

UPDATE:
This whole command becomes quite a bear, so let's use an alias to clean it up:
[image: prints command 3 times, filling up half of screen]

```bash
git config --global --edit
```

Add few aliases:

```
  next = "!sh -c 'git add --all && git commit $@ && git rebase --continue' -"
  redo = !echo "$(git log -1 --format=%B HEAD)" > $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG && git undo && git restore --staged $(git diff --name-only --staged --diff-filter=ard) > /dev/null 2>&1 || true && cat $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG && echo '' && git -c advice.addEmptyPathspec=false add -N $(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard) > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
  review-stack = "!GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=: git rebase --exec 'git redo' --strategy recursive --no-reschedule-failed-exec --strategy-option theirs --interactive"
```

Finally, using alias:

```
git review-stack 315abbd5b

# Go to next commit, no frills:
git next --no-edit --no-verify

# If you made changes:
git next
```

Comment: This could be used to create a whole PR workflow, independent of your typical git hosts. Simply create an alias, `git approve-commit`, which will add some sort of "Signed-off-by: $(git config user.name)" to commit messages... Very rudimentary, yes, also not something I'll be doing anytime soon.

Comment: @torek have you ever needed to do something like this? I have a horribly confusing variable name at the bottom of my pr stack :(

Comment: git `review-stack` alias is dangerous. It probably shoudn't use `--strategy theirs`.

Answer (score 0):

Prep:

1. Add these git alias's:

```bash
git config --global --edit
```

Paste in

```
[alias]
  next = "!sh -c 'git add --all && git commit $@ && git rebase --continue' -"
  redo = !echo "$(git log -1 --format=%B HEAD)" > $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG && git undo && git restore --staged $(git diff --name-only --staged --diff-filter=ard) > /dev/null 2>&1 || true && cat $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG || true && echo '' && git -c advice.addEmptyPathspec=false add -N $(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard) > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
```

<sub>redo is a beast, I am NOT good at bash, basically cobbled this together using google + SO</sub>

2. To pre-populate `COMMIT_EDITMSG` with your last commit message, setup these git hooks. Instructions here are just for husky for now, if you aren't using husky, it's even easier, just put hooks into `.git/hooks` dir.

```bash
# using worktrees:
LOCAL_GITIGNORE=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/../main-worktree/.git/info/exclude
# not using worktrees:
LOCAL_GITIGNORE=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/info/exclude

echo ".husky/prepare-commit-msg" >> $LOCAL_GITIGNORE
echo ".husky/pre-rebase" >> $LOCAL_GITIGNORE
echo ".husky/post-rewrite" >> $LOCAL_GITIGNORE
echo ".husky/post-commit" >> $LOCAL_GITIGNORE
chmod +x .husky/prepare-commit-msg
chmod +x .husky/pre-rebase
chmod +x .husky/post-rewrite
chmod +x .husky/post-commit
code .husky/prepare-commit-msg .husky/pre-rebase .husky/post-rewrite .husky/post-commit
```

`.husky/prepare-commit-msg` is unique:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
# COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
# SHA1=$3

if [ -f $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG ]; then
  # vscode commits happen to run with this command:
  #   git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - [3774ms]
  # So, we won't want to use the last commit message in that case.
  # LAST_COMMIT_MSG will be cleaned up post-commit, if commit succeeds
  # 
  # TODO:
  #   if commit msg from vscode is empty (first line of $COMMIT_MSG_FILE is empty),
  #   And second line starts with a "#"
  #   then actually fill in the missing commit message!
  #   Maybe we can read `COMMIT_SOURCE=$2`
  #   instead of reading the `$COMMIT_MSG_FILE`
  #   https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+check+if+first+line+of+file+is+empty
  if [ "$(git config user.useConfigOnly)" != "true" ]; then
    cat $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG $COMMIT_MSG_FILE > temp_commit_msg && mv temp_commit_msg $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
    # It's been used once, get rid of it?
    # rm $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG;
    # This is cleaned up in post-commit hook.
    # So you can abort commit, edit more, re-commit, and still retain this commit message.
  fi
fi
```

The remaining 3 are all the same:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

if [ -f $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG ]; then
  # echo "some git hook: wiping $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG: $(cat $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG)"
  rm $GIT_DIR/LAST_COMMIT_MSG
fi
```

## Launch it!

```
git rebase --exec 'git redo' -i 315abbd5b
```

### next commit

```
git next
```

### To focus in on a certain variable name throughout a PR, you could run:

```
git rebase --exec 'ag -0 -l newVarNameOfInterest app/greenfield/project && git redo || echo "ok"' -i 315abbd5b
```

<sub>to install `ag` run `brew install the_silver_searcher`</sub>

Comment: This could be used to create a PR workflow, independent of your typical git hosts. Simply create an alias, `git approve-commit` (similar to `git next`), which will add some sort of `"Signed-off-by: $(git config user.name)"` to the end of commit messages. May want to use `git blame-someone-else` to retain original authorship.

Comment: Lastly, it would be nice if there was a way to tell vscode to open all the files you want to edit in a pure diff-like view like github.com. Basically, make the file buffers non-scrollable, and scrolling actually moves you through diffs. And, of course, why not integrate commenting on diffs too, while we are at it.

Comment: This can be nicely simplified by using the `git commit --reedit-message=<sha>` flag, this would also fix the loss of newlines, and retain timestamps of original authors.

Comment: It seems that `exec git undo --soft` has this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338182/configure-git-rebase-to-not-continue-if-there-are-new-untracked-files - which `git redo` doesn't have (via the --intent-to-add flag)