# Configure git rebase to not continue if there are new/untracked files?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-config

I'd like git rebase to never continue if there are new/untracked files.

Sometimes, during an interactive rebase, I run:

```
exec git undo --soft
```

<sub>(`git undo` is from tj's [git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras))</sub>

However, sometimes the commit I want to edit, simply adds new files.
In this situation, the `exec git undo --soft` will not pause rebase.
My commit I want to edit, will have effectively disappeared, the rebase will finish, and then.. the rebase completes, and I have the untracked files just sitting in my working directory.

Is there a way to configure git rebase to not simply continue when there are untracked files?

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase -i` stops after any `exec` line which has a non-zero exit code. So you could [check for untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2657935/112968) in a separate exec line or by executing the check last in your exec line

```
pick deadbeaf some commit to pick
exec git undo ...
exec u="$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard) && test -z "$u"
pick c0ffeeba or you could use the next line:
exec git undo ...; u="$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard) && test -z "$u"
```

Of course the "is something untracked" check can be put into a shell script or a custom git alias, so the `exec` line becomes shorter, e.g.:

```
git config --global alias.hasuntracked '!u="$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)" && test -z "$u"'
```

and then in your rebase todo list just:

```
pick beefb015 another commit
exec git undo ...; git hasuntracked
```

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned this right away: `stops after any _exec_ line which has a non-zero exit code`. Could I also just directly `exec git undo --soft && exit 1;`?

Comment: Ok, turns out that statically doing `exit 1` doesn't work well. When you are all done, commit, run `git rebase --continue`.. you will then be thrown BACK into editing the commit AGAIN, to break the loop, you need to `git rebase --edit-todo` and then delete the `exec git undo --soft && exit 1` line.. then `git rebase --continue`.. and you'll actually continue..

Comment: @DevinRhode yes, the `exec` line will be retried. If you have for example `exec make test`, you don't want to continue if your tests still fail :)

Comment: yeah, it's almost like git rebase should create a new `test` command, a slightly different version of `exec`. `test` gets rescheduled automatically, while `exec` only runs once.

Comment: While we are at it, git should also add a `redo` command too, which is kinda like `edit` but pops your changes into working directory.